# Cookies and Sessions and preventing multiple logins

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with an Intranet site written in asp.net and C#.  We want to prevent users from opening a new tab or a new instance of IE9 while they have an active session.  In other words, we don't want them to have the same page open twice.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Don't do that.  It's extremely annoying.

Comment: @SLaks Sometimes its needed to prevent a user from having a page open two or more times. A lot depends what the application is designed to do.

Comment: If your aim is to prevent multiple logins, then in page you have constantly send some data to server- say you have dropped a cookie, when server received 2 cookie at a time, means multiple logins, you need to invalidate the older one.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the app, but it is designed to log people's time.  If they open more than one tab, they can log two (or more) times simultaneously.  I need to prevent the users from doing this.

Comment: You cannot prevent users from opening a new tab or a new instance.  The best you can do is handle it on the server.

Comment: @MobyDisk - Hewlett Packard has an application called HP Service Manager that we use on our Intranet.  It does this exact thing.  However, I'm not positive what language it's written in.  Are you saying it's not possible *period*, or it's not possible with asp.net?

Comment: You can't prevent this using technical solutions, because you can not prevent that someone is sending self created headers instead of filling in forms using windows or tabs.

Comment: Are you are saying that HP Service Manager would somehow stop me if I clicked the start menu, ran internet explorer, and navigated to the URL of the HP Service Manager web site?  What happens when you try?

Comment: @MobyDisk - Service manager is an Intranet application, so you can't navigate to it unless your company has it.  However, when I log on and open another window, it prompts me with a message that says I have another session open and gives me an "OK" button.  I click OK and the new tab launches.  However, when I go to the old tab it tells me my session has ended.  So, essentially it prevents me from being logged on twice, which is what I'm trying to do as well.  However, I just found out it's a Java applet, and I know nothing at all about Java.

Comment: try this http://blog.startq.com/2013/03/28/prevent-multiple-tabs-on-c-web-applications/